# Dictionary made with C but misleading search

Tags: c, syntax

While I was making a dictionary using C it showed me the meaning of the word which is not present in the dictionary itself. I checked the function for checking the equality of two strings and its working fine but when I implement that function in the lookup function of the dictionary where it searches for the word shows me the meaning of the word it is not working as I intended it to do. I am not looking for a good performance I was just revising my basics in the function and simple boolean functions.
Here is the Code:

```
    struct Entry
{
    char word[50];
    char defination[500];
};

bool isEqualString(const char str1[], const char str2[])
{
    bool flag = true;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (str1[i] == str2[i])
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    if ((str1[i] == str2[i]) && str1[i] == '\0')
        flag = true;
    else
        flag = false;

    return flag;
}

int Lookup(const struct Entry dictionary[], const char search[], int entries)
{
    int i;
    bool isEqualString(const char str1[], const char str2[]);

    for (i = 0; i < entries; i++)
    {
        if (isEqualString(search, dictionary[i].word))
        {
            printf("%d and its indice = %d\n", isEqualString(search, dictionary[i].word), i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void main()
{
    struct Entry dictionary[2] = 
    { {"Hello", "It means hi."},
      {"Dead", "It means you are dead"} };
    int Lookup(const struct Entry dictionary[], const char search[], int entries);
    int entries = 2, searchEntry;
    char searchWord[10];

    printf("Give us a word to find in the dictionary: \n");
    scanf("%s", searchWord);

    searchEntry = Lookup(dictionary, searchWord, entries);

    if (searchEntry != (-1))
        printf("\n%s %s", dictionary[searchEntry].word, dictionary[searchEntry].defination);
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own string comparison function?  Is this an exercise?  It's buggy and poorly written.  It will index past the end of `str2` if `str1` is longer.  And you forgot to `break` the loop when a non-match is found (which would make it much faster and avoid the array bounds bug).  All you need to do when a non-match is seen is return false immediately.  In fact, that initial loop doesn't really do anything, since `flag` is true upon entering and is set to true in the loop body.  So the loop does nothing.

Comment: `I checked the function for checking the equality of two strings and its working fine` - No it isn't.

Comment: OT: regarding the prototype: `int Lookup(const struct Entry dictionary[], const char search[], int entries);`  This should be at the top of the file, immediately after the definition of the struct.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", searchWord);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful output an error message to `stderr` and exit the program.  2) when using the input format conversion specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

the logic in this function:

bool isEqualString(const char str1[], const char str2[])

is not quite right.

Suggest:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isEqualString(const char str1[], const char str2[])
{
    bool flag = true;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < (strlen(str1)+1); i++ )
    {
        if ( str1[i] != str2[i] )
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Note: that whole function can be replaced with: `if( strcmp( str1, str2 ) == 0)`